# How to send text to the Password field within https://mail.protonmail.com registration page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I make proton signup form but it's not typing a password

It's doing all good its typing username but it's not typing a password

It's typing username but it's not typing password.

Code trials:

'''python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://protonmail.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-short' and @href='signup']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//p[text()='Basic account with limited features']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right' and @id='freePlan']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='usernameWrap']//iframe[@title='Registration form']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @id='username']"))).send_keys("Hamza_Mirchi")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='password']"))).send_keys("Hamza_Mirchi")
```

'''

Error Name:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\proton-mail.py", line 16, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='password']"))).send_keys("Hamza_Mirchi")
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Could you copy the HTML for the element please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Password**  field as the the desired element outside of the `<iframe>` so you have to:

- `switch_to_default_content()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Code Block:

    ```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://protonmail.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-short' and @href='signup']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//p[text()='Basic account with limited features']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right' and @id='freePlan']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='usernameWrap']//iframe[@title='Registration form']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @id='username']"))).send_keys("Hamza_Mirchi")
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']"))).send_keys("Hamza_Mirchi")
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: protonmail_password]

Comment: Thank You Very Much You Are The Best :) again Thank you very much you are the best!