# How to interact with the reCAPTCHA Solve the challenge button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, captcha

I'm trying to interact with the recaptcha *Solve the challenge* button on image verification popup using Selenium and Python.

The xpath looks correct in dev tools but using Selenium unable to interact with it. What is the problem?

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@id, "solver-button")]'))).click()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ***Never post code, markup, or data as images!***  It frustrates searching, reproduction of problems, and verification of solutions.   Post as text, formatted as code.  You should [edit] your post and fix this ASAP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once you click on the [recptcha](/questions/tagged/recptcha) and get redirected to the image challenges, the picture elements are within another sibling `<iframe>`. So you have to:

- Switch back to the [default_content()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455).
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='solver-button']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: recaptcha_iframe]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to interact with the reCAPTCHA audio element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077053/how-to-interact-with-the-recaptcha-audio-element-using-selenium-and-python/59078719#59078719)
- [How to send text to the Password field within https://mail.protonmail.com registration page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455)

---

### Outro

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: captcha gived me try again later how to fix?