# How to bypass ReCaptcha with buster extension using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

Currently, I automate some processes using selenium and need to solve Google ReCaptcha. The technology used to solve the ReCaptcha is the browser, Plugin Buster. I enter the Google ReCaptcha using the following

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
check_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor")))
check_box.click()
```

Now I switch back to the default Frame using:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

So I need to  click the Buster icon, but how to do that?

Icon to click:

[image: Icon to click]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Buster** *icon* is within another sibling `<iframe>`. So you have to:

- Switch back to the [default_content()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455).
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='solver-button']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: recaptcha_iframe]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to interact with the reCAPTCHA audio element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077053/how-to-interact-with-the-recaptcha-audio-element-using-selenium-and-python/59078719#59078719)
- [How to send text to the Password field within https://mail.protonmail.com registration page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455)

---

### Outro

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)

Comment: solver-button is now inside a closed shadow DOM. Last line of your code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @abbr any ideas for closed shadow DOM?

Comment: @NamVu, I Submitted an issue to Buster github about closed shadow DOM. Author of buster replied Buster is not designed for automated testing script and deleted the issue ticket.