# How to switch back from iFrame index to the relative parent?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyhook

How to switch back from iFrame index to the relative parent in (Python)?
I use this code but not working for me :

```
def type_order_credit_card1_number(self, credit_card_1_number):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 80).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[1]')))
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 80).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.order_credit_card_number_text_id))).send_keys(credit_card_1_number)

    time.sleep(4)

def type_order_credit_card_expiry_date(self, credit_card_1_expiry_date):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 80).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[2]')))
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 80).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.order_credit_card_expiry_date_text_id))).send_keys(
        credit_card_1_expiry_date)
```

I want to switch from [selectFrame index=2] to [selectFrame relative=parent] to type credit card expiry date and cvv (the card number works fine)

Answer (score 0):

To switch back from child `<iframe>` to the immediate parent `<iframe>` you need to use the [`switch_to()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) statement as follows:

```
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

To switch back from any of the child or grand child `<iframe>` to the *Top Most level* i.e. the *default content* you need to use:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [Way to switch back to the default content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455)

Answer (score 0):

I have chage my code by using TAB to type number but always it type one number for the second tab (to type cvv number) it type just 7 not 737!

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 80).until(
         EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.order_credit_card_number_text_id))).send_keys(Keys.TAB,'1223', Keys.TAB, '737')
    time.sleep(4)
```