# How to close iframe in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I'm working on a Selenium webdriver Project, and, in one of the process, I needed to enter in na iframe, and then, send Keys to the input in there, but, now I want to close or exit that iframe to can click in a button outside that frame, check out me code piece:

```
WebDriverWait(bot,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.top[title='Registration form']")))
WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="username"]'))).send_keys(self.usernameChar)
WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="username"]'))).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Can you guys help me?
Note: My google version is the 85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exit from any `<iframe>` and set [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s focus on the *Top Browsing Context* you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to send text to the Password field within https://mail.protonmail.com registration page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142447/how-to-send-text-to-the-password-field-within-https-mail-protonmail-com-regist/57143455#57143455)